# AngularJS. Use template in several places

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a table which displays list of products. And I display same table for "All products" page and for "My products" page. This is part of this table:

```
<tr ng-repeat="product in products>
  <td>{{product.id}}</td>
  <td>{{product.name}}</td>
```

Both "All products" and "My products" pages has own controllers where I setup the `$scope.products` variable.

Can I exclude definition of this talbe to separate file and use it for both "All products" and "My products" pages?

Comment: you can setup a directive with the template.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it by initializing the products variable in the parent controller...
And remember when you use [ng-include](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude) it creates its own scope , so be careful while using any ng-model for any input in the child file (i.e. the file which is to  be included..)

Never assign ng-model to a primitive in the child file

Better refer this : [What are the nuances of scope prototypal / prototypical inheritance in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs/14049482#14049482)

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-include`. Yes you can create a table.html file with those contents

Or, you can even create an inline angular template

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="table.html">
    <tr ng-repeat="product in products>
        <td>{{product.id}}</td>
        <td>{{product.name}}</td>
    </tr>
</script>
```

Then include wherever you want:

```
<div ng-include="'table.html'"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate html page first:

table.html

```
<table>
<tr ng-repeat="product in products>
    <td>{{product.id}}</td>
    <td>{{product.name}}</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Then include it:

```
 <div data-ng-include="table.html"></div>
```